# CodeIgniter checkboxes

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

[image: this is the screenshot]

I have this code which shows 10 sets of checkboxes and I want that only 1 set of checkboxes can be checked at a time and then sent to the database.

But errors show when I leave another set of checkboxes unchecked. It says

#### Error

```
Severity: Warning
Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed 
And column field cannot be null.
```

Please, help this is my first question here hope someone can help.

```
<table class = "table">
<tr>
    <td colspan = "6"><strong>Please check the following boxes related to end-user's role:</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Requestor:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("requestor[]","Purchase Request/Service Request", set_checkbox("requestor[]","Purchase Request/Service Request")); ?><i> Purchase Request/Service Request <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("requestor[]","Work Order", set_checkbox("requestor[]","Work Order")); ?> Work Order</i></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><td><strong>Planning, Process and Plant Performance:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("planning[]","Planner (Mech, Elec, I&C and Process Engr.)", set_checkbox("planning[]","Planner (Mech, Elec, I&C and Process Engr.)")); ?><i> Planner (Mech, Elec, I&C and Process Engr.) <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("planning[]","Planning Head", set_checkbox("planning[]","Planning Head")); ?> Planning Head</i></td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Approver:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("approver[]","Site Approver (Plant Manager/Deputy GM)", set_checkbox("approver[]","Site Approver (Plant Manager/Deputy GM)")); ?> <i>Site Approver (Plant Manager/Deputy GM) <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("approver[]","VP, SVP, CFO, EVP, President", set_checkbox("approver[]","VP, SVP, CFO, EVP, President")); ?> VP, SVP, CFO, EVP, President</i></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><td><strong>Finance Accounting and Budget:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("financeacctg[]","AP Officer", set_checkbox("financeacctg[]","AP Officer")); ?> <i>AP Officer <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("financeacctg[]","Inventory Accountant/Controller", set_checkbox("financeacctg[]","Inventory Accountant/Controller")); ?> Inventory Accountant/Controller <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("financeacctg[]","Budget Officer", set_checkbox("financeacctg[]","Budget Officer")); ?> Budget Officer</i></td>
</tr>           
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Procurement:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("procurement[]","Procurement Staff/Encoder", set_checkbox("procurement[]","Procurement Staff/Encoder")); ?><i> Procurement Staff/Encoder <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("procurement[]","Buyer", set_checkbox("procurement[]","Buyer")); ?><i> Buyer <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("procurement[]","SPO-Site Procurement Officer", set_checkbox("procurement[]","SPO-Site Procurement Officer")); ?><i> SPO-Site Procurement Officer <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("procurement[]","Materials Management Head", set_checkbox("procurement[]","Materials Management Head")); ?> Materials Management Head</i></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><td><strong>Management Information System:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("mis[]","MIS ICT", set_checkbox("mis[]","MIS ICT")); ?><i> MIS ICT<br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("mis[]","MIS SYSDEV", set_checkbox("mis[]","MIS SYSDEV")); ?> MIS SYSDEV</i></td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Warehouse: Receiving and Inventory Issuances:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("warehouse[]","Warehouse Store-man", set_checkbox("warehouse[]","Warehouse Store-man")); ?><i> Warehouse Store-man <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("warehouse[]","Warehouse Supervisor", set_checkbox("warehouse[]","Warehouse Supervisor")); ?> Warehouse Supervisor</i></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><td><strong>Internal Audit:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("internalaudit[]","Intra-Company Audit Team", set_checkbox("internalaudit[]","Intra-Company Audit Team")); ?><i> Intra-Company Audit Team <br>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><strong>Work Management:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("workmgmt[]","Requestor-Work Order(Operations)", set_checkbox("workmgmt[]","Requestor-Work Order(Operations)")); ?><i> Requestor-Work Order(Operations)<br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("workmgmt[]","Servicing Group: Mech, Elect, GSU, I&C, PDG", set_checkbox("workmgmt[]","Servicing Group: Mech, Elect, GSU, I&C, PDG")); ?> Servicing Group: Mech, Elect, GSU, I&C, PDG</i></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><td><strong>Accreditation and Fuel Management:</strong><br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("accredfuelmgmt[]","Accreditation Officer", set_checkbox("accredfuelmgmt[]","Accreditation Officer")); ?><i> Accreditation Officer <br>
        <?php echo form_checkbox("accredfuelmgmt[]","Fuel Manager/Staff", set_checkbox("accredfuelmgmt[]","Fuel Manager/Staff")); ?> Fuel Manager/Staff</i></td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: are you want to Allow grouping like Radio buttons?

Comment: yes. they are grouped under different set. for example.: the planning head and the planner is grouped under planning.

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle ?

Comment: i dont know how. sorry i just started coding.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will:

- Allow grouping of Radio buttons
- Act like Radio
- Allow unselecting all

[**Here's a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ankit29/g161j5re/3/)

```js
// the selector will match all input controls of type :checkbox
// and attach a click event handler 
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
    // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
    // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table class = "table">
        <tr>
            <td colspan = "6"><strong>Please check the following boxes related to end-user's role:</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><strong>Requestor:</strong><br>


             <input type="checkbox" name="">

                <input type="checkbox" name="requestor[]" value="Purchase Request/Service Request"  />
<i> Purchase Request/Service Request <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="requestor[]" value="Work Order"  />
 Work Order</i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><td><strong>Planning, Process and Plant Performance:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="planning[]" value="Planner (Mech, Elec, I&amp;C and Process Engr.)"  />
<i> Planner (Mech, Elec, I&C and Process Engr.) <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="planning[]" value="Planning Head"  />
 Planning Head</i></td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><strong>Approver:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="approver[]" value="Site Approver (Plant Manager/Deputy GM)"  />
 <i>Site Approver (Plant Manager/Deputy GM) <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="approver[]" value="VP, SVP, CFO, EVP, President"  />
 VP, SVP, CFO, EVP, President</i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><td><strong>Finance Accounting and Budget:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="financeacctg[]" value="AP Officer"  />
 <i>AP Officer <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="financeacctg[]" value="Inventory Accountant/Controller"  />
 Inventory Accountant/Controller <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="financeacctg[]" value="Budget Officer"  />
 Budget Officer</i></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><strong>Procurement:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="procurement[]" value="Procurement Staff/Encoder"  />
<i> Procurement Staff/Encoder <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="procurement[]" value="Buyer"  />
<i> Buyer <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="procurement[]" value="SPO-Site Procurement Officer"  />
<i> SPO-Site Procurement Officer <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="procurement[]" value="Materials Management Head"  />
 Materials Management Head</i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><td><strong>Management Information System:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="mis[]" value="MIS ICT"  />
<i> MIS ICT<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="mis[]" value="MIS SYSDEV"  />
 MIS SYSDEV</i></td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><strong>Warehouse: Receiving and Inventory Issuances:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="warehouse[]" value="Warehouse Store-man"  />
<i> Warehouse Store-man <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="warehouse[]" value="Warehouse Supervisor"  />
 Warehouse Supervisor</i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><td><strong>Internal Audit:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="internalaudit[]" value="Intra-Company Audit Team"  />
<i> Intra-Company Audit Team <br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><strong>Work Management:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="workmgmt[]" value="Requestor-Work Order(Operations)"  />
<i> Requestor-Work Order(Operations)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="workmgmt[]" value="Servicing Group: Mech, Elect, GSU, I&amp;C, PDG"  />
 Servicing Group: Mech, Elect, GSU, I&C, PDG</i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><td><strong>Accreditation and Fuel Management:</strong><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="accredfuelmgmt[]" value="Accreditation Officer"  />
<i> Accreditation Officer <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="accredfuelmgmt[]" value="Fuel Manager/Staff"  />
 Fuel Manager/Staff</i></td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Enhed12345 please try and tell me is it helpful or not?

Comment: thanks for the help @ankit. but im trying to do the code without javascript. thanks

Comment: then use radio button it will do work as your need @enhed12345

Comment: Or if you can add your controller code it would be very helpful to solve this issue @enhed12345

Comment: yes @ankit like radio buttons, but you cannot deselect a radio button once clicked even by mistake. Thanks anyway